# How to totally remove a certbot-created SSL certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl, bash, configuration, certbot

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx and I've installed Nginx Certbot on my operating system (Ubuntu 16.04) with:

```
apt-get update -y
add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot -y
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade python-certbot-nginx -y
```

I setted Nginx variables:

```
s_a="/etc/nginx/sites-available"
s_e="/etc/nginx/sites-available"
```

I created an app conf based on these variables:

```
sed "s/\${domain}/${1}/g" "~/${repo}/template_nginx_app" > "${s_a}/${domain}.conf"
ln -sf ${s_a}/${domain}.conf ${s_e}
```

I created a correspondent SSL certificate with Certbot based on the app conf, this way:

```
certbot --nginx -d ${domain} -d www.${domain}
```

---

There are cases an SSL certificate is created in a bad way and one just need to start over after some configurations.

How could I totally remove the SSL certificate (besides removing the app conf `${domain}.conf` which was also edited/reconfigured by Certbot) ?

Is there a fast way to do that directly from Certbot? My desire is that no remnants whatsoever would left for both app conf and certificate.

This might be the good way:

```
rm ${s_a}/${domain}.conf && rm ${s_e}/${domain}.conf
rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/{live,renewal,archive}/{${DOMAIN},${DOMAIN}.conf}
```

Comment: I would delete the VM and start over. Not strictly necessary, but the cleanest as it forces you to have correct install scripts.

Comment: @JohnMahowaldor better yet, nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 74):

Yes, certbot can help you clean up.

`sudo certbot certificates`

will list what certbot thinks you have installed

`sudo certbot delete`

will allow you to interactively remove and clean up unwanted / deprecated domains.

Comment: after run, all of encrypt error did u know , i cant create a new cert . from apache to nginx . ```The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\nnginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/``` after delete the cert

Comment: please more guide how to solve because in my conf there is no point to load the file but the error is always on appears :(

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo, it might be necessary to edit server configuration files like /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (see also /etc/nginx/conf.d/), removing ssl instructions from certbot, to reliably delete references to outdated certs.

Answer (score 14):

Get the certificate's name that will delete

```
sudo certbot certificates
```

Delete only one certificate by the name

```
sudo certbot delete --cert-name server.domain.tld
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are running apache2 you will also want to remove the certbot references from the conf file otherwise certbot will get confused when you add a new certificate.

```
sudo certbot delete
```

then

```
emacs /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf
```

Remove these lines

```
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf 
ServerName example.com 
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```